# lcov shows my code does not covered by test but actually it did

Tags: c, testing, lcov

I found my coverage report generated by the lcov is not correct. I'm sure some code lines be tested according to the log I print out. But the coverage report shows it did not.

The code is written in C language. The compile flags is '-g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage".
I wonder if someone encountered the same problem and know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem finally. Since my program will be intentionally terminated by sending signal. The gcov need flush before the program exit. Now the result is correct.

Comment: How did you flush it???